# Can a computer have an ip address without an operating system

Tags: networking, ip-address

If a system does not have an operating system can it have an IP address?

Comment: Yes, but I would doubt if it could be called as a computer. These are not so exact things.

Comment: ALU (Arithmetic Logic Unit) + CU (Control Unit) = CPU (Central Processing Unit ). CPU+ Memory Array = Computer (or System)

Answer (score 2):

It could. UEFI includes network stack which can be either configured with static IP address from ie. UEFI shell or HII forms or can obtain it from the network using DHCP. Similarily when legacy PXE boots it also obtains IP address using DHCP.

Please note however that this doesn't mean this address will be reachable from the outside. Usually there are no services in this case which would respond and even ping may not work (depending on the implementation).

Comment: But then UEFI would act as operating system, so the answer is actually no. On top you forget the really simple example of ISCSI network boot where the networ kcards NEEDS to get an IP to reach out to the boot server, or the case ff BMCs.

Comment: One can argue if UEFI is an OS or not, let's not start it here :). I know about iSCSI and there are more, including HTTP boot or some other technologies people are looking at to perform boot. Not sure about BMC you mention, in this case it is COMPLETELY different entity from HOST CPU and as such doesn't seem to fit the question.

Comment: Well, not necessarily. Let's take out BMC and use Intels Management tools that actually DO use the Host CPU for a fake BMC. What IS the computer? This needs to be defined.

Comment: I thought that every computer comes with NIC card in it which may have IP address and MAC associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is no, because you need something to ask for the IP address and network cards do not do that themselves. Some network cards can do that, though, to facilitate booting over DHCP - but then the question is whether or not you consider the booting code in the network card some kind of OS that then hands over to another OS?

The real answer is more complex and based on really bad wording. My servers, for example, have no OS installed, but get an OS after boot. Not using ISCSI. See, there is a daughterboard on the motherboard that has it's own OS and is used for BMC (i.e. remote control, i.e. i can turn on an off computer, make changes to the bios screen, install the main OS). Would you consider this an OS or not?

Comment: FWIW: Cisco even calls it router/switch software (IOS) " Internetwork Operating System" ...